# Why when creating screenshot captured files on hard disk and make of them avi it's very slow?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

What i mean is i have this code i'm creating many gif files on the hard disk using a timer to capture the desktop window. Every 1 second i'm taking a screenshot.
For example after 60 seconds i have on the hard disk only 60 gif files.

Then i'm using my own animated gif class to create animated gif.
When i'm playing the animated gif it seems that many frames are missing.

Now i'm taking screenshots of the dekstop window every second a screenshot.
But i think i should take every second like 25 screenshots or 60 ?
How can i do it ?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;
using System.IO;
using unfreez_wrapper;

namespace CapturedDesktop
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        int screens;
        string gifsdirectory;
        UnFreezWrapper unfreez;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            unfreez = new UnFreezWrapper();
            screens = 0;
            gifsdirectory = @"C:\Temp\CapturedDesktop\";
        }


        private void CaptureScreenshot()
        {
            screens++;
            screenshots(gifsdirectory + screens.ToString("D6") + ".gif");
        }

        public static void screenshots(string filename)
        {
            //Create a new bitmap.
            using (var bmpScreenshot = new Bitmap(Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width - 100,
                                           Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height - 100,
                                           PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb))
            {
                // Create a graphics object from the bitmap.
                using (var gfxScreenshot = Graphics.FromImage(bmpScreenshot))
                {

                    // Take the screenshot from the upper left corner to the right bottom corner.
                    gfxScreenshot.CopyFromScreen(Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.X,
                                            Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Y,
                                            0,
                                            0,
                                            Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Size,
                                            CopyPixelOperation.SourceCopy);
                }
                // Save the screenshot to the specified path that the user has chosen.
                bmpScreenshot.Save(filename, ImageFormat.Gif);
            }
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            CaptureScreenshot();
        }

        private void AnimatedGifButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            List<string> myGifList = new List<string>();
            FileInfo[] fi;
            DirectoryInfo dir1 = new DirectoryInfo(gifsdirectory);
            fi = dir1.GetFiles("*.gif");
            for (int i = 0; i < fi.Length; i++)
            {
                myGifList.Add(fi[i].FullName);
            }
            unfreez.MakeGIF(myGifList, gifsdirectory + "agif", 100, true);
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is not the animated gif speed when i create it but it's not smooth it's like missing frames.

Comment: To take more images you lower the Timer's Interval; but the speed will also be limited by the speed of your system, which will not be quite the same all the time. So try not to hit that limit! The quality of playback will also depend on your system's speed; displaying a full screen's worth form a GIF may well be too much.

Comment: The most glaring mistake is you assuming that you read the files back in the same order as you created them.  That's not how a disk works, only the way Explorer works.  You'll have to sort them and avoid files that are still on disk from a previous recording session.